# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object " during extract value from database

Tags: razor

```
public ActionResult updateisrc()
        {
            AlbumSongModel s = new AlbumSongModel();
            List<mainISRC> listalbum = Class1.GetAllAlbum();

            s.listalbum = listalbum.Select(x => new SelectListItem   **
            {
                 Value = x.Album.ToString(),    
                 Text = x.Album
            });

            return View("updateisrc", s);
        }
```

I have marked as "**" the line I am getting error. Please help me

Comment: listalbum might be null, check if it has got any members

Comment: listalbum has 1115 no. of rows.

Comment: Check if any of the row has null value for album i.e x.Album

Comment: no one row has null value sir.. I have checked it....

Comment: Please show ur AlbumSongModel class definition

Comment: thanx sir.. I got solution

Answer (score 1):

x itself or x.Album may be null. Try this

```
listalbum.Where(a=>a != null && a.Album != null).Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
                 Value = x.Album.ToString(),    
                 Text = x.Album
});
```

Hope this helps.
-Mahesh